# JSF performance problems with ajax requests

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jboss

I am trying to find a bottleneck in a web-application running on JBoss.

I have a module that contains forms for which when moving from field to field I do some server side validation of the data, using Ajax (those validations take below 1 ms). The modules are used in two separate web applications:

- One running on Apache Tomcat Application Server, where each
  validation takes about 200-400ms;
- Second one running on JBoss 7.1.1, where each validation takes about
  3-5 sec. The problem here is that I have the exact same modules as those used on the Tomcat and the 5sec delay is really not an option.

I've measured the times anywhere I could, but I couldn't find any bottlenecks in the application, running on JBoss.

So I used JProfiler and thread dumps to try find the problem. Here's a screenshot of the result.

To me it looks like a problem in jsf/richfaces, but I am not sure for the exact reason and what can be done to fix this.

I'm using:

- jboss 7.1.1, patched with jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1
- Richfaces 4.2.3.Final
- jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.Final-redhat-1

What I've tried is: using the latest richfaces version, changing the viewstate of jsf to server side, enable partial state saving.

Here's JProfiler screenshot:

[image: JProfiler screenshot]

From it for me it seems that the performance issue here is with javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentHandler.applyNextHeader

I am running out of ideas, any hits would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. Web latencies can easily exceed what you observe in Tomcat. You should restrict per-field AJAX calls to what is strictly necessary, and do as much as possible at submit time.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that the measured execution time as shown in screenshot is cumulative.

Comment: Balrus: yes I know it's cumulative I was simply trying to measure what takes most time. EJP yes, I try to restrict the calls as much as possible but the ajax calls are done from one and the same module, which is included in two different webapps, so the calls should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your JSF `PROJECT_STAGE` if it is development. If so, try changing it into production.

You can do it by removing the `<context-param>` with name of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` from your `web.xml`, or set its value to `Production` instead of `Development`.

Comment: This worked, could you, please, include the reason the development stage causes such problem?

Comment: The PROJECT_STATE information allows the JSF implementation to optimize its behavior for the current stage. 

For example, the JSF  implementation might provide more verbose development-time diagnostics than would be practical for a production environment.

Doing this enables better error messages but this come with the cost of some performance.